# superposition of electron and how it is used to prove quantum entanglement

Tags: quantum-entanglement, superposition

The superposition of electron is the following:

[image]

I read that in the Stern Gerlach experiment, the electron was only measured as either spin up or spin down: only rows three and four in the image were observed. However, there was never an instance that both electrons were spin up or spin down. Does that mean that the possibilities of the superposition of electrons is wrong? That is, it can never be both spin up or spin dow?

Finally, how is superposition used to prove entanglement?

That is, how is the info that electrons either are spin up or spin down prove that there is a dependence on each electron?

Answer (score 1):

Superposition is simplest to think about in regard to a single particle, which can be in a state of spin up, spin down, or a superposition of those.   Entanglement is a kind of superposition that involves two particles, where you are superimposing states where each particle has a definite spin state that is opposite the other.  So both spin states appear in the superposition, but every time the definite state of one spin is opposite the other.  So both superposition and entanglement appear in quantum mechanics, entanglement is a more sophisticated form of superposition because it is a superposition of several two-particle states.

Comment: sorry but when you say entanglement is a kind of  superposition that involves two particles, in the picture above, I have 2 particles.

Comment: But no entanglement.  In quantum mechanics, any time you take two possible states for a 2-particle system, you can also form a state by adding them.  So if you regard up/down as one state for the two electrons, and down/up as a second state, then you can add those two.  That would be an entangled state.  Any time one electron was found to have spin up, the other would have spin down, but either particle could have either spin.  More to the point, you get interesting correlations between the measurements on the two particles, which have been described as "spooky."  Google Bell's theorem.